# MYSQL Left join fails with "unknown column" in java

Tags: java, mysql, left-join

I have a Spring Boot application running Spring boot 2.2.5, 
mysql-connector-java version 5.1.38

In my application I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  role.id AS roleid,
  roles.id,
  role_name,
  role_description,
  contact_name,
  roles.employee_mail,
  contact_phone
FROM
  rcsa.fs_role AS ROLE
  LEFT JOIN rcsa.fs_customer_roles_external AS roles
    ON roles.fs_role_id = role.id AND fs_customer_id = :account
  LEFT JOIN rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts AS cont
    ON roles.employee_mail = cont.contact_email
WHERE role_type_id = 2
GROUP BY role.id,
  employee_mail
```

When I run this query in my mysql admin console, it returns the following result:
[image: Correct result]

Which is what I want it to return.

However, when I try to run this query from inside my Spring boot appliation, it throws an exception:

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select role.id as roleid,
>        roles.id, role_name, role_description, contact_name, roles.employee_mail , contact_phone from
>        rcsa.fs_role as role  left join rcsa.fs_customer_roles_external  as roles    on
>        roles.fs_role_id=role.id and fs_customer_id=? left join rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts as 
>       contacts on contacts.contact_email=roles.employee_mail  where role_type_id=2 group by role.id,
>        employee_mail]; SQL state [S0022]; error code [0]; Column 'contact_email' not found.; nested
>        exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'contact_email' not found

I have tried swapping the order og the columns in the second on clause, but to no avail.
I guess the error comes from the order of my joins, where I start with the fs_role table, but this is intentionally so that any unassigned roles also get returned.

EDIT:

In my original question the queries were not identical, as I had been experimenting to see if I could find a solution, the problem still persists when the queries are identical.

EDIT 2:

I turned on the mysql transaction log and both the queries are present in it:

```
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
Time                            Id  Command Argument
2020-03-06T12:39:15.942813Z     8   Query   SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
2020-03-06T12:39:18.568670Z     9   Query   SET autocommit=0
2020-03-06T12:39:18.569841Z     9   Query   select role.id as roleid, roles.id, role_name, role_description, contact_name, roles.employee_mail , contact_phone from rcsa.fs_role as role  
                                            left join rcsa.fs_customer_roles_external  as roles    on roles.fs_role_id=role.id and fs_customer_id=1010499  
                                            left join rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts as cont on roles.employee_mail=cont.contact_email  
                                         where role_type_id=2 group by role.id, employee_mail
2020-03-06T12:39:18.574042Z     9   Query   rollback
2020-03-06T12:39:18.574299Z     9   Query   SET autocommit=1
2020-03-06T12:39:18.952383Z     8   Query   SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
2020-03-06T12:39:20.048826Z     2   Query   select role.id as roleid, roles.id, role_name, role_description, contact_name, roles.employee_mail , contact_phone from rcsa.fs_role as role 
                                            left join rcsa.fs_customer_roles_external  as roles    on roles.fs_role_id=role.id and fs_customer_id=1010499 
                                            left join rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts as cont on roles.employee_mail=cont.contact_email 
                                            where role_type_id=2 group by role.id, employee_mail
```

The first query originates from my java code and the second from my mysql workbench.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: Maybe you are not using the same DB?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose But *mysql admin console* is OK

Comment: @ScaryWombat Then it is not the same DB! Really, If it is correct, then the error would not occur!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Same database

Comment: Also, it's good practice to qualify all column names, regardless of where they appear. It makes the query much clearer when you come back to review it later - or want to share it with others!

Comment: rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts please check this table one more time and cross-check your db connection.

Comment: @Andreas Programs seldom (better: never) behave in such an unexpected manner. Go and find out the difference. We cannot do that here! It would only be wild guessing.

Comment: Either the query is not the same, or the db is not the same - can not see any other possibilities.

Comment: `and fs_customer_id =?` these are two different queries

Comment: updated the question now, the problem persists with both versions of the query.
IE. even though run with identical queries the problem still occurs.
I will do some more digging in the mysql logs to see what I can find there.

Comment: I have added more information now, but I am still not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error was not from the MYSQL server, but from the java application.
I was fetching contact_email from the resultset and populating an object with this, and this was where the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different queries

```
select r.id role_id
     , e.id
     , role_name
     , role_description
     , contact_name
     , e.employee_mail 
     , contact_phone 
  from rcsa.fs_role r 
  left 
  join rcsa.fs_customer_roles_external e
    on e.fs_role_id = r.id 
  left 
  join rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts c
  on e.employee_mail = c.contact_email  
 where role_type_id = 2 

   and fs_customer_id = :account 

 group 
    by r.id
     , employee_mail

select r.id role_id
     , e.id
     , role_name
     , role_description
     , contact_name
     , e.employee_mail
     , contact_phone 
  from rcsa.fs_role r 
  left 
  join rcsa.fs_customer_roles_external e
    on e.fs_role_id = r.id 

   and fs_customer_id =? 

  left 
  join rcsa.fs_business_service_contacts c
    on c.contact_email = e.employee_mail  
 where role_type_id = 2 

 group 
    by role.id
     , employee_mail
```

Answer (score -3):

try to use like this for the all columns `select role.id as roleid` => `select role.id as 'roleid'`

Comment: sounds like a wild guess.